# Is consuming maltodextrin a good idea for replenishing energy between games?

Tags: nutrition

this weekend my amateur team will be competing in a tournament (Quidditch - you can consider it as a high intensity exercise for 60 minutes.). We will play 4 games in a day with 1 or 2 hours between the games. Would it be a good idea to consume 150-200 calories of maltodextrin dissolved in water to replenish energy right after each game?

Comment: related, possible duplicate: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/290/refuelling-during-a-run/349#349

Comment: This question is about energy supply "right after" high intensity activity. The other one is about energy supply *during* the activity. Furthermore this question is limited to "maltodextrin dissolved in water". The other one is broader. I would never provide comparable answers.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Maltodextrin is absorbed almost as fast as grape sugar aka dextrose aka glucose.
It is just an industrial replacement of pure starch.

While glucose can be useful for drinks consumed during the games, it is not recommend for restitution.
You will need slower carbohydrates preferably combined with smaller amounts of fat and protein to stabilize your blood sugar in the break and last during the next game.
Even 150-200 kcal is a "small" meal compared to supposedly 600 kcal burned during the 60 minutes game, your body prefers a stable supply of energy.

If you feel like your blood sugar is low right after the game and you need a boost, I will suggest you to eat a banana, which contains about that amount of calories you ask for and small amounts of fat and protein.
It is absorbed much faster than whole grain products, but not as fast as maltodextrin dissolved into water.